# What alignment is Action Mode?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In Mass Effect 3, one of the options you have to play the game in is called "Action Mode." In this mode, you don't choose your conversation options, they're instead chosen for you, so the game plays out a little more like a typical action game rather than an RPG.

However, in the past 2 games, major decisions between Paragon and Renegade choices often played out very differently in the cinematic. Seeing as (I assume) those choices are made for you, what alignment is an Action Mode playthrough? Is it Paragon, Renegade, or a mix of both?

Comment: I've seen it stated that Action Mode will go through the dialogs using a mix of Paragon, Renegade, and neutral responses, but I can't find that source right now. I do not know if charm/intimidate options will also be used/available, or how much choice the player will be given for big decisions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Action Mode features 'a mix of Paragon and Renegade dialog options'. It can also be turned on or off at any time using the 'Narrative' settings, simply by toggling between 'Full Decisions' or 'No Decisions', so you can always save your game, turn it on, and see what version of an interaction plays out if you're curious.