# Are Action Mode responses random?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Mass Effect 3 has an "[Action Mode](http://www.webcitation.org/query?url=http://www.gamepro.com/article/news/224705/mass-effect-3-beta-leak-reveals-three-different-campaign-modes/&date=2011-11-30%2019:07:36)" where story responses [are apparently picked between Paragon/Neutral/Renegade choices](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53596/what-alignment-is-action-mode).

Are the choices Action Mode makes randomly picked or will all Action Mode playhtroughs have an identical story and make identical "decisions"?

Comment: Purely guessing, it's probably somewhat random, but the choices at any particular dialogue tree may be weighted based on numerous factors such as current alignment, last item picked, and if optional trees should be completed.

Comment: @MBraedley I'm mostly wondering because I wonder if there's a "single" playthrough for Action Mode of it *is* trying to automatically guess your alignment based on your gameplay actions...or if it's totally random.

Comment: @Ben Bioware has been very clear that action mode is **not** intended to be canonical. It's merely a middle of the road composite.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Canonical was a poor choice of words, I meant a single experience that *all* Action Mode players have, storywise. Of course Action Mode's story isn't binding, as many/most players (like me) probably won't even play it.

Comment: Casey Hudson basically says there's no canonical way to play Mass Effect, there is only your way, even in Action Mode.  [link](http://www.gameinformer.com/b/features/archive/2012/01/10/mass1525-effect-3-cas5ey-fdsafdhudson-interviewae.aspx?PostPageIndex=3)

Comment: Also, if it's trying to guess your desired alignment, the only thing it really has to go on is Paragon/Renegade interrupts, as the only other way to change your alignment is through dialogue.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of "What Alignment is Action Mode" because I'm asking whether the responses are random or preset, whether it has a chosen alignment is a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

As BioWare executive produer Casey Hudson explains it to Game Informer, these choices are basically difficulty and auto-fill settings for people who expect different things from the Mass Effect experience.

"You have to make a game with a certain design before you realize that there are different player types," Hudson said. "One of the surprising pieces of feedback was for some players, it's not that they don't like the story. They love story. In fact, the story is so important to them that they feel the story choices are intimidating

The story setting will make it more difficult to die and makes the action scenes easier, so players can mow through enemies, Hudson said. The action mode fills in default dialogue that grants players access to a lot of interesting things, but "it's not canon," Hudson said. "We have a rule in our franchise that there is no canon."

so basically its this Story: Full convo choices, easy combat difficulty Action: auto convo choices, normal combat difficulty Roleplaying: Full convo choices, normal difficulty.

http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:Sovereign777/Mass_Effect_3_campaign_details_from_Casey_Hudson_offer_you_a_choice

Comment: I know they're automatic, I'm jsut asking if they're random or if all players get the same choices.

Comment: "The action mode fills in default dialogue" implies everybody would get the same settings, the clarification that these default choices are not canon seems to further back this up.

Comment: @Kalina: Makes sense but the answer could probably be cleaned up a bit to focus a bit more on the actual answer without all the other fluff.