# These decision are too hard

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What alignment is Action Mode?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53596/what-alignment-is-action-mode)

So, when I was changing some options in the options menu, I noticed something very weird (for a Bioware game at least). Under Options > Narative, there is an option called "Conversation Mode" and it allows you to toggle Full Decisions vs No Decisions.

And this piqued my curiosity. If you choose No Decisions, how does the game make the decisions. Most decisions are Paragon vs Renegade, so does it choose what your alignment leans towards, or does it just choose a default set of answers chosen by the developers throughout the game?

Comment: Ah, yup, it's a dupe. Interesting that it is named "action mode" though. Didn't see that setting anywhere, but it obviously the same.

Comment: It's referred to as Action Mode when creating a new game.

Comment: And you can only choose it when you don't import a character from a previous game.